# Проблемы с electron

Tags: electron, окно

написал я простенькую игрушку с помощью electron. При создании главного окна

```
win = new BrowserWindow({...});
```

Я указал `frame: false`. В самом приложении я сделал свою панель управления для закрытия/сворачивания приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть файл `app_control.js`, в котором есть следующий код:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var close = document.querySelector('#close');
close.addEventListener("click", () =>  {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
});
```

Проблема (максимально мне непонятная) такая:
    кнопка не работает, если `frame: false`, но если `frame: true`, то есть с кнопками windows:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То тогда всё прекрасно работает. (Моя кнопка). Но тогда, сами понимаете, торчат 2 панели управления, что, конечно, никуда не годится. Открыть консоль и посмотреть где возникают ошибки можно только с `frame: true`, а сама ошибка возникает только при `frame: false` :) Что делать?

P.S - сомневаюсь, что даже если бы я мог открыть отладчик, я бы нашел ответ. Судя по всему это просто недоработка electron.

Comment: win - окно  в котором хочешь взаимодействовать с консолью; `win.openDevTools()` - открыть консоль; `win.closeDevTools()` - закрыть консоль; `win.toggleDevTools()` -универсальный переключатель состояния консоли, открывает её если закрыта и закрывает если открыта;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На всю панель управления было css правило:

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```

В класс `button`, который есть у всех кнопок, я добавил:

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```

И всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    icon:__dirname + "/img/icon.png",
    center: true,
    maximized: true,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    skipTaskbar: true,
    frame: false,
  });
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).